# HttpClient 4.1 does not return host value all the time

Tags: java, httpclient

If you run the following code, you will see that the URI has a value of "null" for Host upon completion.  This is invalid!  It should always have a URI after executing a request.

I am trying to get the current page from the context after the page is requested (in case redirects occurred).

I apologize for the confusion.  I mentioned the redirect because I thought it would help illustrate my problem more easily.  The code below should work for pages that were redirected and those that were not.

Plug in your favorite site, it doesn't matter.  The final solution has to work for ANY site... those that were redirected and those that were not.

What am I missing?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/");
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpclient.execute(httpGet, context);
    HttpUriRequest currentReq = (HttpUriRequest) context.getAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    System.out.println("New URI host (why is it null?): " + currentReq.getURI().getHost());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html)

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/"); 
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
// here:
HttpHost target = (HttpHost) localContext.getAttribute(
        ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
```

Comment: I am trying to get the new URI - the current URI.  If you test with 'pttp://boards.cityofheroes.com/register.php' it will redirect you to 'pttps://boards.cityofheroes.com/register.php'   NOTICE the **https** instead of **http**.  I need to get pttps://boards.cityofheroes.com/register.php since it is the "current" page.

Comment: @bigleftie: The URL you provide does not do an HTTP redirect. It does some sort of javascript-based redirection. HTTP client will never process this automatically. I tried my example with `http://app.portasigma.com` (which does a proper http redirect to `https://`...) and it does indeed work

Answer (score 0):

Android codes?

Why code in main? I think there should be not main method in programs other than JavaSE.
HttpGet is already the HttpUriRequest object, why not use it?

I am not quite an expert, maybe this could help.

Comment: who said anything about Android?

Comment: It is a sample program to demonstrate the bug.  And, it has nothing to do with Android... plain old Java.  I want to get the "current page" AFTER the request is made, in case the requested page contained a redirect that was followed.

Comment: Google has "borrowed" Apache HttpCore HttpClient to Android SDK since its under ASF2.0 licensed that allowed them to do that freely.